# How can be shown the placeholder sync icon in a renamed folder using Win32 Cloud Filter API?

Tags: c++, winapi, filesystems, c++-winrt

I'm using the Microsoft [Cloud Filter API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_cloudapi/) to manage placeholders in my local directory, and when I rename a folder its state icon isn't visually updated after I apply the [CfSetInSyncState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfsetinsyncstate) function to this folder. This folder contains a file that was previously copied from another placeholder from this cloned directory. I've applied several functions besides [CfSetInSyncState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfsetinsyncstate) as [CfUpdatePlaceholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfupdateplaceholder), [CfSetPinState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfsetpinstate), [CfRevertPlaceholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfrevertplaceholder) and [CfConvertToPlaceholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfconverttoplaceholder) to the folder but the sync icon isn't shown properly and I checked that the placeholder has the CF_PLACEHOLDER_STATE_IN_SYNC state. Is there some way to set the sync icon properly in this case?

*Sync state icon correctly shown before rename a folder.*

[image: Sync state icon correctly shown after sync the renamed folder.]

*Sync state icon isn't visually updated after sync a renamed folder.*

[image: Sync state icon isn't visually updated after sync the renamed folder.]

Comment: First thing is to compare the folder's file attributes and check they are consistent. (Note make sure you read them using the registered cloud sync engine process or another process after making placeholders are exposed RtlQueryProcessPlaceholderCompatibilityMode otherwise you'll read false info). Then check placeholder sync state. Then if everything is ok, it maybe a Shell issue (System.SyncTransferStatus and/or System.FilePlaceholderStatus)

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks so much for your comment, in this case I think that could be a Shell issue because I made sure that the only file inside the folder and the folder have the placeholder and in sync states and the reparse point attribute.

Comment: @SimonMourier if you have some suggestion taking account my previous comment I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Try to reset the properties (PKEY_StorageProviderTransferProgress , PKEY_SyncTransferStatus) like how it's done here: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/CloudMirror/CloudMirror/Utilities.cpp#L53

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried your suggestion but it didn't work, I could solve this issue renaming the folder twice as I show in my own answer. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could show the placeholder sync icon correctly in this case renaming the folder twice using [MoveFileW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefilew) and [CfUpdatePlaceholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfupdateplaceholder) functions. Here I show you the method that renames the folder twice.

```
bool FolderRenameTrick(const std::wstring& folderPath)
{
    // Gets a nonexistent folder path
    std::wstring folderPathAux = GenerateAuxPath(folderPath);

    if (folderPathAux != L"")
    {
        bool renamed = false;
        
        // Renames the folder with MoveFileW method (auxiliary folder)
        if (MoveFile(folderPath.c_str(), folderPathAux.c_str())) 
        {
            // UpdatePlaceholder calls internally to CfUpdatePlaceholder (auxiliary folder)
            if (UpdatePlaceholder(folderPathAux)) 
            {
                renamed = true;
            }
        }

        if (renamed)
        {
            // Renames the folder with MoveFileW method (correct folder)
            if (MoveFile(folderPathAux.c_str(), folderPath.c_str()))
            {
                // UpdatePlaceholder calls internally to CfUpdatePlaceholder (correct folder)
                if (UpdatePlaceholder(folderPath))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call both CfSetInSyncState and CfSetPinState.
First set the file in Sync State , and after that update the pin state accordingly.

Comment: [lulian Rotaru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4145425/iulian-rotaru) I tried your function combination suggestion before I wrote the question but it didn't work in my case. I could solve the issue as I show in my own answer. Anyway thanks for your comment.